# Как инициализировать сервис значением из другого сервиса?

Tags: angular2, внедрение

Допустим, есть сервис авторизации  куда приложение стучится при запуске, что получить пользователя и его права.

Так вот, я хочу создать еще 1 сервис в котором централизованно заложена логика доступа к страницами и инициализировать его пользователем, который получился в результате работы сервиса авторизации.

Как я могу это сделать?

Самое просто - это внедрить в сервис контроля прав сервис авторизации. Но что-то мне кажется, что не совсем корректно так делать...

Я могу как-нибудь иначе поступить?

Comment: _Но что-то мне кажется, что не совсем корректно так делать..._ - почему?

Comment: _Но что-то мне кажется, что не совсем корректно так делать..._ - приведите хоть аргументы, которые вас смущают? :)

Comment: @overthesanity ну типа зачем передавать в сложны объект и брать от него совсем чуть чуть, если можно сразу передать все нужно?

Comment: @iluxa1810 я не понимаю :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, сделал так, так как не хотел, что бы 1 сервис что-то знал о существовании другого сериса:

Создал в корневом маршруте `resolver`, который запрашивает в конструкторе эти 2 сервиса.

Затем `resolver` запрашивает все необходимые данные из одного сервиса и по готовности передает в другой сервис.