# Как правильно сделать отображение контента в зависимости от прав?

Tags: angular2

Допустим, есть разные страницы сайта, где нужно отображать различный контент в зависимости от прав.

Есть 2 сервиса:

1)

```
export class AuthorizationService {
     private _currentUser: User = new User();
     constructor(private _userService: UserService, private _roleService: RoleService) {
          this.authorize().subscribe();
     }
     authorize() {
          const roleObs = this._roleService.getRolesByUser(this._currentUser.id).pipe(map(roles => {
               this._currentUser.roles = roles;
          }));
          return this._userService.getCurrentUser().pipe(map(user => {
               if (!user.id) {
                    this._currentUser.login = 'Гость';
                    return;
               }
               this._currentUser = user;
               roleObs.subscribe();
          }));
     }

     get currentUser(): User {
          return this._currentUser;
     }
}
```

2)

```
    export class PermissionService {
         private currentUser: User;
         constructor(authService: AuthorizationService) {
              authService.authorize().subscribe(() => {
                   this.currentUser = authService.currentUser;
              });
         }

     canAddComment(): boolean {
          return this.checkExistsAction(4);
     }

...
    }
```

Соответственно, там, где нужно ограничивать контент должен будут в конструкторе запрашивать `PermissionService` и далее использовать методы can* для проверки разрешения.

Однако, если так делать, то может быть момент, когда `PermissionService` еще не получил права юзера(все же асинхронное...).

Т.е мне нужно, что бы независимо от того куда пользователь перейдет(допустим, он может сразу в адресную строку вбить интересующую его страницу миную главную) ровно один раз выполнилась первичная инициализация PermissionService, которая не даст открыться страницы пока она не будет выполнена до конца.

Читал про `Resolver'ы` и что-то подобное мне и нужно. Однако, получается, что я их должен на каждый маршрут повесить и `Resolver` должен запрашивать в конструкторе PermissionService? Как я понимаю, в этом случае мне придется проверять наличие инициализированного юзера в `PermissionService` и возвращать либо `Ovservable`(если юзера нету), либо return `PermissionService`(если была инициализация)?

**UPD**

[Линк](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%40Injectable()%0D%0Aclass%20PermissionResolver%20implements%20Resolve%3CAny%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(private%20auth%3A%20AuthorizationService%2Cprivate%20permService%3AAuthorizationService%20)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%20%0D%0A%20%20resolve(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20route%3A%20ActivatedRouteSnapshot%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20state%3A%20RouterStateSnapshot%0D%0A%20%20)%3A%20Observable%3Cany%3E%7CPromise%3Cany%3E%7Cany%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20obs%3Dauth.authorize()%0D%0A%09%09%09obs.subscribe(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20permService.currentUser%20%3D%20auth.currentUser%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%09%09%09%20%20return%20obs%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: я уже вам когда-то говорил за резолверы

Comment: @overthesanity да, но про них я как раз пишу в самом низу.

Comment: я не видел, не нужно на каждый маршрут, нужно на 1

Comment: @overthesanity т.е достаточно в корневой маршрут повесить resolver и он будет действовать на всех маршрутах независимо от того с какой страницы юзер начал посещение? Resolver вызовется один раз или по разу на каждом маршруте?

Comment: 1. - http://tiny.cc/mwto6y 2. - один

Comment: @overthesanity тогда Resolver будет ~ таким? См. обновленный вопрос.

Comment: http://tiny.cc/umwo6y

Comment: @overthesanity оформи ответом. По идее, это даже чуть перекликается с этим: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/980937/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0 , так как permissionService ничего не знает об сервисе ауторизации.

Comment: @overthesanity почему-то не работает=(( У меня вот такой роут const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', redirectTo: '/Main', pathMatch: 'full', resolve: [PermissionResolver]
  }
]; вообще точка останова не срабатывает в методе resolve=(...

Comment: @overthesanity похоже, что редирект убивает resolve, так как без него все работает или я что-то не то делаю=(

Comment: тебе редирект нужен в `children`, посмотри мой пример с роутами который я тебе скинул чуть выше, у тебя просто есть 1 роут "обертка" и от него уже пляшут дети

Comment: @overthesanity если делать ленивую загрузку, как вы написали, то ловлю такую ошибку Error: No module factory available for dependency type: ContextElementDependency. Если в childer делать так   path: '', resolve: { data: PermissionResolver }, children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/Home', pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ], то резольвер не вызывается -(

Comment: @overthesanity так... с ленивой загрузкой я проблему решил. Оказывается был какой-то еще 1 webpack внутри какого-то модуля...

Comment: В общем, вешаю resolver на пустой маршрут, в children лениво гружу модуль, а внутри этого модуля уже делаю нужный мне редирект. Вроде, работает.

Answer (score 0):

Какой способ авторизации? Токен? Логин/Пароль?

От этого зависит в какой момент вы получаете эти разрешения.

**Вариант с токеном**

Разрешения ( в дальнейшем "клеймы" ) получаются вместе с токеном. Токен имеет "время жизни". Соответственно клемы живут столько же. Следовательно токен можно спокойно сохранить в `localStorage`. Следовательно, ваш сервис берёт данные из хранилища и вам ненужны никакие резолверы. До данного сервиса дойдёт, только если `guard` авторизации пропустит, если нет, то перебросит на страницу логинаи грохнет токен в `localStorage`.

**Вариант с Логин/Пароль**

Разрешения ( в дальнейшем "клеймы" ) получаются после авторизации или "следом". Соответственно клемы живут пока "авторизованы" или не закрыли вкладку. Следовательно токен можно спокойно сохранить в `sessionStorage`. Следовательно, ваш сервис берёт данные из хранилища и вам ненужны никакие резолверы.

**Общая часть**

Хотелось бы сразу предупредить, что необходимо реализовать директиву типа `*ngIf`, которая на вход принимает `ключ разрешения` и в сервисе проверяет наличие разрешения по ключу. Если такой находит, то отображается контент иначе скрывается раз и на всегда. Избегайте передавать в него функции, это приведёт к постоянному вызову данной функции, что со временем "обрушит" страницу.

Comment: виндовая аутентифипкация.

Comment: Не сталкивался, но на вскидку, получается, что в принципе достаточно запросить 1 раз клеймы и жить они будут покак жива страница. Следовательно достаточно хранить их в ``sessionStorage``. Если данные есть, то пользуемся ими (переходы по урлам, перезагрузка и т.д), если данных нет, то как предлагалось на корень повесить резолвер и загружать там.

Comment: @SergeyRogachev резолверы это концепция оптимизации в angular, которая позволяет обработать асинхронную логику до инициализации приложения, в конечном счете компоненте получают готовые чанки данных. Использование `ngIf` или реализация своих директив, которые "на вход принимает ключ разрешения" влечет за собой комбинаторную сложность и выделение кучи памяти. `Избегайте передавать в него функции, это приведёт к постоянному вызову данной функции, что со временем "обрушит" страницу.` - [от Мишко](https://angular-checklist.io/default/checklist/components/ZXcqct)

Comment: @SergeyRogachev >  `что со временем "обрушит" страницу`, это обрушит страницу если функция выполняет какие-то просчеты, если функция возвращает ссылку на объект - например `[ngStyle]="getNecessaryStyles()"`, компилятор помечает эту функцию горячей после 3х вызовов и производит "инлайнинг"

Comment: А что по вашему будет в условной функции ``can*``? Будет вычисление. Постоянно вычисление того, что достаточно вычислить 1 раз ил скрыть навсегда. А для примера, представьте 500 строк таблицы, в которой у вас скрываются клеймами 4 колонки и того получаем, 500 * 4 = 2000 вызовов вашей функции, вызываться они будут постоянно. Каждая функция это залезть в массив . Вроде мелочи ... но это постоянно!

Comment: @SergeyRogachev `canSeeSomething(): boolean { return this.isAuthenticated }` - я не вижу здесь вычисления. И зачем залезать куда-то в массив? oO

Comment: Перечитайте топик! Зависимость от прав - это говорит, о том, что будет массив каких то разрешений, а не просто авторизован/неавторизован. Что то вроде ``hasAccess(claim): boolean { return this.permissionService.hasClaim(claim) }``, где ``hasClaim(claim): boolean { return this.claims.includes(claim)}``

Comment: @SergeyRogachev, я такое впервые вижу